# Multiple answer question creation by users in android app

Tags: android, layout

I am creating an app for android devices that allow people to create their own survey.
Creating "yes or no" question is pretty straight forward but for multiple answers questions things become more complicated.
What I would like to implement is something similar to the telegram poll creation that you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpKg9.jpg).
Do you have any idea on how I can design the activity for this? Should I use a listView? Or dynamically add element to a layout?

Answer (score 0):

Using a ListView or a RecyclerView is probably a good idea. The items of the view would be the different answers (like in your example from Telegram), but the "Add"-Button and everything else would be kept separate in your Activity Layout (e.g. LinearLayout).

For more information see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview